# UICollectionView is not displaying any cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uicollectionview

I've tried everything to make the cells apear even re-do everything usaing tutorials and another questions of stack, but was not sucessfull. I need help, this is my code:

I am using the following code in XCode 6 with Storyboards and iOS 8. Everything is set correctly like the tag etc.

```
#import "LMSceneCollectionViewController.h"

@interface LMSceneCollectionViewController () {
    NSArray *sceneIcons;
}

@end

@implementation LMSceneCollectionViewController

static NSString * const reuseIdentifier = @"Cell";

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Register cell classes
    [self.collectionView registerClass:[LMSceneCollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    sceneIcons = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    sceneIcons = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Cenario_Desligar.png", @"Cenario_Manhã.png", @"Cenario_Tarde.png", @"Cenario_Noite.png", @"Cenario_Filme.png", @"Cenario_Festa.png", @"Cenario_Romântico.png", @"Cenario_Plus.png", nil];

}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

#pragma mark <UICollectionViewDataSource>

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return sceneIcons.count;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    LMSceneCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell
//    UIImageView *sceneImageView = (UIImageView *) [cell viewWithTag:100];
//    sceneImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[sceneIcons objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
//    cell.alpha=1.0f;
    cell.imageScene = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[sceneIcons objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
    cell.textScene.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

#pragma mark <UICollectionViewDelegate>

/*
// Uncomment this method to specify if the specified item should be highlighted during tracking
- (BOOL)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView shouldHighlightItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;
}
*/

/*
// Uncomment this method to specify if the specified item should be selected
- (BOOL)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;
}
*/

/*
// Uncomment these methods to specify if an action menu should be displayed for the specified item, and react to actions performed on the item
- (BOOL)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView shouldShowMenuForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return NO;
}

- (BOOL)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView canPerformAction:(SEL)action forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath withSender:(id)sender {
    return NO;
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView performAction:(SEL)action forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath withSender:(id)sender {

}
*/

@end
```

Comment: Where did you make your cell? In a storyboard or xib, or entirely in code? And, please, when you post code, don't post all that irrelevant commented out code.

Comment: Have you set the class of the prototype collection view cell in your storyboard to LMSceneCollectionViewCell?

Comment: If you made the cell in the storyboard, you should not register the class. Only register the class if you've made the cell entirely in code.

Comment: Why wouldn't you register the cell class in the storyboard?

Comment: I'm sorry for the mistakes, this is my first post.
I made my cell in a storyboard. I set the dataSource and delegate in the storyboard. I set the class in the storyboard to.
Take a look on the screenshots [link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/xyr9rru62ft7kdd/AABQCk6opBpTSHAh6wnn0vxsa?dl=0)

Comment: @mcjoejoe0911, registering the class, tells the collection view where to get the cell from. If the cell's views are made in a storyboard, then you want the collection view to get its cells from there, not the class (which doesn't define the views). The cell will still be of that class (assuming you change the cell's class in the storyboard).

Comment: Did you try commenting out the registerClass line?

Comment: @rdelmar it worked. I commented out the registerClass. Thanks!

Comment: @GabrielTargon Of course, the new structural of the model here presents trends to approve the maintenance of innovative management to which we belong. I like this, What do you think?